The call was rejected, Twilio still sent in-progress status callback events
When I made a call using the Twilio API, I refused to answer, but I still received in-progress status callbacks.

Twilio call initializer

func TestCall(t *testing.T) {
    client := twilio.NewRestClient()

    params := &api.CreateCallParams{}
    params.SetFrom("xxx")
    params.SetTo("xxx")

    params.SetStatusCallbackEvent([]string{"initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"})
    params.SetStatusCallback("{API_URL}/hook/status")
    params.SetStatusCallbackMethod("POST")

    xml := `<Response>
        <Say>Hello.</Say>
    </Response>`

    params.SetTwiml(xml)

    resp, err := client.Api.CreateCall(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        if resp.Sid != nil {
            fmt.Println(*resp.Sid)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(resp.Sid)
        }
    }
}


status callback

router.POST("/hook/status", func(c *gin.Context) {
    callSid := c.PostForm("CallSid")
    callStatus := c.PostForm("CallStatus")
    fmt.Printf("==== hook status %s %s\n", callSid, callStatus)
})


I refuse to answer the phone
Log result

initiated
ringing
in-progress
completed

Why am I still receiving in-progress status callbacks when I refuse to answer the phone?
Should the in-progress status callback occur only during the call?

Is it possible that the call goes to your mailbox when you reject it? That would explain this behavior

That doesn't seem to be the case, because I didn't set up any mailbox.
